# Will upgrading from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2008 R2 affect any existing databases?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm amazed at ReportBuilder 3.0. This might be just what I need for my job. I haven't thoroughly checked the differences between SQL Server 2008 and its R2 version so I don't know if upgrading would be a hassle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server 2008 to R2 is quite minor. Especially compared from SQL Server 2000, say.

Be warned: once your databases are upgraded, they can not be restored on an install of an older version. It's a quite common question on StackOverflow and ServerFault...

Comment: R2 databases cannot be restored on non-R2 2008 SQL Server?

Comment: @Jonn: **No** There is an internal version number in each database and you can only restore *up* to a SQL Server instance of a higher version. The same applies to service packs too.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade should work with all your existing databases. Just to make sure, perform a full backup before upgrading, of course.

Answer (score 2):

We had that transition on our systems, and had no problems at all.